# Extract <data-id > from HTML with JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm new in Jsoup an i'm trying to scrap some datas from website using Jsoup.
I want to extract only datas under specific  `<data-id>` node.
this is the webpage structure

```
<tr data-id="13">
  <td class="th">Dimension</td>
  <td class="l">152.5x82x9.8mm (6x3.23x0.39")</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even" data-id="15">
  <td class="th">Weight</td>
  <td class="l">190gr (6.7oz)</td>
</tr>
<tr class="h" data-id="116">
   <td class="th">Ringtone</td>
   <td class="l"></td>
</tr>
```

I need to get something like this

1. **Dimension**
2. **190gr**
3. **Ringtone**
   Please Help me.

This is what i tried

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    final Document document =  Jsoup.connect("url").get();

    String testString = document.select("table")
            .select("tbody").select(".even")
            .select("td.l").text();
    System.out.println("the tile is "+testString);
    }
}
```

This is the output: 152.5x82x9.8mm (6x3.23x0.39") 190gr and so on

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried this  final Document document =  Jsoup.connect("url")..timeout(6000).get();       String testString = document.select("table")
                .select("tbody").select(".even")
                .select("td.l").text();
        System.out.println("the tile is     "+testString);                                                                   But i'm getting all nodes at same time

Comment: Add your comment to the question itself, so that other people have an easier time to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Document out = Jsoup.connect("https://www.phonegg.com/phone/9858-Energizer-Power-Max-P600s-32GB/%22")
            .timeout(15000).get();
    String dimension = out.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-id", "13").get(0).getElementsByClass("l").text();
    String weight = out.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-id", "15").get(0).getElementsByClass("l").text();
    String rington = out.getElementsByAttributeValue("data-id", "116").get(0).getElementsByClass("l").text();
```